# Is this correct way to prove that { $uv$ $\mid$ $u$ and $v$ are strings over $(0,1)$ & $|u| = |v|$ } language is not regular?

Tags: automata, regular-language

I proved this using Pumping Lemma in the following way,

Taking $p$ as pumping length then let us take a string $S$ where, $|u| = |v| = p$

Now according to pumping lemma $S$ can be split into three parts, $$S = xy^{i}z$$

where, $|xy| \le p$ & $|y| \gt 0$.

So now, if $|y| \gt 0$ and taking $i=0$ in $S = xy^{i}z$ will lead to $|u| \lt |v|$ which is not in the language $L$. Thus, this language is not regular.

Is this correct usage of Pumping Lemma?

Edit: This language is regular. See the comments below.

Comment: The language **is** regular: it’s just the set of words over $\{0,1\}$ of even length, so it’s $(00+01+10+11)^*$. Your argument fails when $|y|$ is even: removing $y$ *does* leave an element of the language in that case.

Comment: If $|u|=|v|$ means that $u$ and $v$ have the same length, then this is just the set of even-length binary strings, which is certainly regular.  Do you mean something else?

Comment: @mjqxxxx No, you are correct. I had an argument with instructor on this. Thus, I am wrong. Language is regular.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes. $|y|$ is a loop. certainly. Thank you professor.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: Would you like an answer to your question, explaining where the error is in your application of the pumping lemma?  Or do you feel that your question has already been answered?

Comment: @MJD Sure, but pumping lemma cannot prove if a language is regular.. So where is the error in application ?

Comment: You made an argument,  based on the pumping lemma, that showed that $L$ is not regular.  But $L$ is regular.  So your argument contains a mistake. It would be instructive for you to identify this mistake.